# How is a php tag embedded in html really executed?

Tags: php

Since php is a server-side language then i expect that all php codes are run on the server and only the final html file is sent to the client.

For example, How is the following code executed?

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<h1>Hello, PHP-7!</h1>";
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Should the server generate the final html file as below before responding to the client's request?

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, PHP-7!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. All server side code (in this example, the PHP code) will be executed on the server. The result is then sent to the client, just like you mentioned.

Comment: Yes it should, presuming you have php installed. Confused about the title though

Comment: Not sure about the indenting though. I believe all will be "left aligned" in your example.